# How do Verilog Compilers Interpret Addition

Tags: verilog

I know that Verilog has an arithmetic add operator. If I'm building an adder, should I make my own or use that? Which will perform better in my processor?

Answer (score 0):

For simulation, the add operator will behave according to the standard and should be fine to use unless you have a reason to simulate a specific adder implementation.

For synthesis, what you get depends on your synthesis tool and final hardware platform. For example, FPGAs usually have dedicated logic for adds and using the Verilog add operator should take advantage of that automatically.

If you need extreme performance on your hardware, it's possible you could do better by using the available primitives directly. Though add is a very common operation and synthesis should be able to handle it well for most use cases.

Comment: What if I'm getting it on a wafer? My school has access to a fab and I want to layout my processor.

Comment: You should ask the fab directly as they may have libraries that they want you to use. If I had to guess, a simple add ought to work just fine with the `+` operator. Maybe someone with more ASIC experience can chime in.

Comment: Will do! Thanks!